# Google cloud messaging not sending notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Hello everyone I am able to get the token from GCM cloud and store it to my data base but when i am going to send notification on the relevant token it's output is something like
 {"multicast_id":8449678444605960595,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}

```
I don't see error in code but if any one of you know please help me.I am not uploading my code because i think it doesn't have any logical error.but if any of you want so i am uploading my php script here

phpScript

 <?php
    //request url
    $url    = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

     $registrationIDs=array();
     $index=0;

    $host = "mysql7.000webhost.com"; 
        $dbname = "a1861947_lalitdb";     
        $username = "a1861947_lalit12"; 
        $password = "kush123"; 

       $con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);




    $apiKey = 'AIzaSyCL-BT0xo6RVB-eLeYKjH-g0n_CdjM9kN0';
     $querySelect="Select Token from token_reg";
         $result=mysqli_query($con,$querySelect);


           while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                 $registrationIDs[$index++]=$record['Token'];
                }

    //payload datad
    $data   = array('Demo'=>'Accenture ne Pinnacle Bna Diya');

    //$data=array('message'=>$message);
    $fields = array('registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,
                    'data' => $data);

    //http header
    $headers = array('Authorization: key='. $apiKey,
                     'Content-Type: application/json');
      $ch = curl_init();

            // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if ($result === FALSE) {
                die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            // Close connection
            curl_close($ch);
            echo $result;

    ?>
```

//token_reg table has the tokens sent by GCM

Answer (score 1):

The value you are passing in the multicast id does not look like a valid GCM token. GCM tokens are much longer than what you have and usually contain letters numbers and some special characters.

If you are registering your device correctly, it is likely an error in the code that saves this token.